# Switch in ListView doesn't fire

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I am filling my settings in list view, however I wanted to leave it generic and just set class like this however when I switch the value it doesn't fire the command
for my switch I have used this to add the command.
It works outside of a list https://damienaicheh.github.io/xamarin/xamarin.forms/2019/05/17/how-to-add-command-to-a-switch-in-xamarin-forms-en.html

```cs
public class Settings
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public Command command { get; set; }
}
```

then I am loading specific settings like this

```cs
public CustomSettingsViewModel()
{
    LoadSetting();
   
}

private void LoadSetting()
{
    foreach (var setting in _customSettings.ScanSettings)
    {
        var detail = new Settings()
        {
            Type = setting.Type,
            Value = setting.Value,
            command = new Command<Settings>((value) => ExecutePageCommand(value))
        };
        Setting.Add(detail);
    }
}
```

command

```cs
private void ExecutePageCommand(Settings settings)
{
    foreach (var result in _customSettings.ScanSettings.Where(d => d.Type == settings.Type))
    {
        var detail = new ScanSetting()
        {
            Value = settings.Value,
        };
    }
}
```

```xml
<Grid  BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}"  x:Name="grid" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ColumnSpacing="0">
  <!--Data-->
  <Label Grid.Row="0" Text ="{Binding Type}"   Style="{StaticResource SubLabelStyle}" HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="End"   />
  <Switch Grid.Row="0"  IsToggled="{Binding Value}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
    <Switch.Behaviors>
      <control:SwitchBehaviour Command="{Binding  command}" />
    </Switch.Behaviors>
  </Switch>
</Grid>
```

However I am unsure how to change the value of the switch on the exact property so it would change only one value. Can you please advise?

Comment: the binding context of each row in the ListView is a `Settings` - and your Command doesn't exist in that class, it is defined on the base VM.  You need to specify a relative binding source if you want to bind to something on the base VM

Comment: ahaaaa, I see thank you

Comment: I have added Command to my model and when loading the items I added   command = new Command<Settings>((value) => ExecutePageCommand(value))

Comment: but still nothing, I updated my question

Comment: I have tried to use button instead of switch and that works on the exact same binding however if I try checkbox then it doesn't work either

Comment: @ikopopo Hi, you mean it works with buttom command however switch command not works? If possible, you could share a sample project with virtual data here. I will check that.